# In $\Delta ABC$ has area $120$ with $AB = 50, AC= 10.$ Let $D,E$ be the midpoints of $AB,AC$ respectively.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, problem-solving, angle

> In $\Delta ABC$ has area $120$  with $AB = 50, AC=  10.$ Let $D,E$ be the midpoints of $AB,AC$ respectively. The angle bisector of $\angle BAC$ intersects $DE$ and $BC$ at $F,G$ respectively. Find the area of quadrilateral $FDBG$.

**What I Tried**: Here is a picture :-

[image]

All the results which I got are in the picture with the appropriate use of Midpoint Theorem as well as Angle Bisector Theorem. Since we are given the area, I can use it to find $BC$ and hence find $x$ . But how am I going to find the area of the trapezium $BDFG$ ?  Also, finding $BC$ using Heron's formula will be a bit difficult algebra, I am wanting for some easy methods here.

Can anyone help? Thank You.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Say $\triangle AFE = a$

Then $\triangle ADF = 5a$ (same height as $\triangle AFE$ but base is $5$ times).

$\triangle AGC = 4a$ (both base and height are double of $\triangle AFE$).

$\triangle ABG = 5 \times \triangle AGC = 20a$ ($\triangle AFE$ and $\triangle AGC$ share the same height but base ratio is $5:1$).

Adding them up $\triangle AGC + \triangle ABG = 4a + 20a = 120 \implies a = 5$.

So area of quadrilateral $= \triangle ABG - \triangle ADF = 20a - 5a = 75$.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the answer.

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

$$[FDBG] = (1-\tfrac{1}{4})[ABG]= \dfrac{3}{4} \cdot \dfrac{5}{6} [ABC]   $$

Since $[ADF] = \tfrac{1}{4}[ABG]$. And $\triangle ABG$ has same height but base $5/6$ th of $\triangle ABC$

> So $$[FDBG] = 75$$

Answer (score 3):

We have
$$
\begin{aligned}{}
[FDBC]
&=[ABG]-[ADF]=[ABG]-\frac 14[ABG]=\frac 34[ABG]\\
&=\frac 34\cdot\frac {BG}{BC}[ABC]=
\frac 34\cdot\frac {AB}{AB+AC}[ABC]
\\
&=\frac 34\cdot\frac{50}{50+10}\cdot 120
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$